# How can I update the parameters of a neural network in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

Let's say I wanted to multiply all parameters of a neural network in *PyTorch* (an instance of a class inheriting from [`torch.nn.Module`](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.Module)) by `0.9`. How would I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let `net` be an instance of a neural network `nn.Module`.
Then, to multiply all parameters by `0.9`:

```
state_dict = net.state_dict()

for name, param in state_dict.items():
    # Transform the parameter as required.
    transformed_param = param * 0.9

    # Update the parameter.
    param.copy_(transformed_param)
```

---

If you want to only update *weights* instead of every parameter:

```
state_dict = net.state_dict()

for name, param in state_dict.items():
    # Don't update if this is not a weight.
    if not "weight" in name:
        continue
    
    # Transform the parameter as required.
    transformed_param = param * 0.9

    # Update the parameter.
    param.copy_(transformed_param)
```

Comment: does this make sense? I would expect some vector operation to perform this operation, otherwise python would kill the speed, and furthermore would this work on GPU?

Comment: @Gulzar Performance impact is almost non-existent. `state_dict` is a small collection (e.g. 10) of references to large tensors (e.g. 16x512x64x64). The `* 0.9` operation is run by external C++ libraries which are usually "vectorized". Calling the `* 0.9` operation from Python is quite cheap (1 microsecond per call * 10 calls = 10 microseconds) since Python doesn't do any of the actual computation.

Comment: BTW, couldn't one do `param.copy_(transformed_param)` to avoid looking up `state_dict[name]` again? I don't think `state_dict` overrides `__setattr__` anyways... in fact it's just an `OrderedDict` that is created only when `net.state_dict()` is called.

Answer (score 1):

A different way of achieving this is using `tensor.parameters()`.

Initialize module:

```py
>>> a = torch.nn.Linear(2, 2)
>>> a.state_dict()
OrderedDict([('weight',
              tensor([[-0.1770, -0.2151],
                      [-0.6543,  0.6637]])),
             ('bias', tensor([-0.0524,  0.6807]))])
```

Change the parameters:

```py
for p in a.parameters():
    p.data *= 0
```

See the effect:

```py
>>> a.state_dict()
OrderedDict([('weight',
              tensor([[-0., -0.],
                      [-0., 0.]])),
             ('bias', tensor([-0., 0.]))])
```