# PyTorch: What's the difference between state_dict and parameters()?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

In order to access a model's parameters in pytorch, I saw two methods:

using [`state_dict`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49446785/how-can-i-update-the-parameters-of-a-neural-network-in-pytorch) and using [`parameters()`](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/explicitly-obtain-gradients/4486)

I wonder what's the difference, or if one is good practice and the other is bad practice.

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `parameters()` only gives the module parameters i.e. weights and biases.

> Returns an iterator over module parameters.

You can check the list of the parameters as follows:

```
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    if param.requires_grad:
        print(name)
```

On the other hand, [`state_dict`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.state_dict)  returns a dictionary containing a whole state of the module. Check its [`source code`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html#Module.state_dict) that contains not just the call to `parameters` but also `buffers`, etc.

> Both parameters and persistent buffers (e.g. running averages) are included. Keys are the corresponding parameter and buffer names.

Check all keys that `state_dict` contains using:

```
model.state_dict().keys()
```

For example, in `state_dict`, you'll find entries like `bn1.running_mean` and `running_var`, which are not present in `.parameters()`.

---

If you only want to access parameters, you can simply use `.parameters()`, while for purposes like saving and loading model as in transfer learning, you'll need to save `state_dict` not just parameters.

Comment: Is there also some third way of accessing parameters, that returns a tensor of all the parameters, for vector operations?

Comment: I think `.parameters()` is the easiest way _(maybe only way)_ to return all parameters. Other methods, if exist, may simply involve a call to it.

Comment: If you could take a look at my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734556/pytorch-how-to-create-an-update-rule-that-doesnt-come-from-derivatives and propose the correct way to implement the update rule, I would be extremely greatful

Answer (score 4):

Besides the differences in @kHarshit 's answer, the attribute `requires_grad` of trainable tensors in `net.parameters()` is `True`, while `False` in `net.state_dict()`

Comment: Can somebody explain why this difference?? Also, i was actually comapring the tensors from model.named_parameters and model.state_dict using torch.equal, even before running the back pass (so no updates ) and the two are different. Any ideas as to why this may be so.