# Pytorch: saving model or state_dict gives different on-disk space occupation

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, pickle

I was playing around with the function `torch.save` and I noticed something curious, let's say i load a model from `torchvision` repository:

```
model = torchvision.models.mobilenet_v2()
```

if i save the model in this way:

```
torch.save(model,'model.pth')
```

I get a 14MB file, while if i do:

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(),'state_dict.pth')
```

The file size blow to ~500MB. Since i didn't find any reference on this behaviour I was wondering what does cause the increment in size. Is it something related to compression? does saving the whole `state_dict` stores extra stuff like uninitialized gradients?

P.S. the same happens for other model like `vgg16`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to save a trained model in PyTorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703500/best-way-to-save-a-trained-model-in-pytorch)

Comment: @dennlinger I already saw that question before asking this one, it doesn't give any hint.

Comment: [PyTorch: What's the difference between state_dict and parameters()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54746829/pytorch-whats-the-difference-between-state-dict-and-parameters?rq=1) gives a bit more insight but the difference between the two is huge

Comment: What is your version of PyTorch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ask for what is in model:

```
vars(vgg16)
```

Out:

```
{'_backend': <torch.nn.backends.thnn.THNNFunctionBackend at 0x232c78759b0>,
 '_parameters': OrderedDict(),
 '_buffers': OrderedDict(),
 '_backward_hooks': OrderedDict(),
 '_forward_hooks': OrderedDict(),
 '_forward_pre_hooks': OrderedDict(),
 '_state_dict_hooks': OrderedDict(),
 '_load_state_dict_pre_hooks': OrderedDict(),
 '_modules': OrderedDict([('features', Sequential(
                 (0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
                 (1): ReLU(inplace)
                 (2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
                 (3): ReLU(inplace)
                 (4): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
                 (5): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
                 (6): ReLU(inplace)
                 (7): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
                 (8): ReLU(inplace)
                 (9): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
                 (10): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
                 (11): ReLU(inplace)
                 (12): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
                 (13): ReLU(inplace)
                 (14): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
                 (15): ReLU(inplace)
                 (16): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
                 (17): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
                 (18): ReLU(inplace)
                 (19): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
                 (20): ReLU(inplace)
                 (21): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
                 (22): ReLU(inplace)
                 (23): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
                 (24): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
                 (25): ReLU(inplace)
                 (26): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
                 (27): ReLU(inplace)
                 (28): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
                 (29): ReLU(inplace)
                 (30): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
               )),
              ('avgpool', AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(7, 7))),
              ('classifier', Sequential(
                 (0): Linear(in_features=25088, out_features=4096, bias=True)
                 (1): ReLU(inplace)
                 (2): Dropout(p=0.5)
                 (3): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=4096, bias=True)
                 (4): ReLU(inplace)
                 (5): Dropout(p=0.5)
                 (6): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1000, bias=True)
               ))]),
 'training': True}
```

You will get it is more than just state dict.

```
vgg16.state_dict()
```

State dict is inside `_modules` (`vgg16._modules['features'].state_dict()`)

This is why when you save the model you save not just the state dict, but also all aforementioned stuff such as parameters, buffers, hooks...

But if you don't use parameters, buffers, hooks for inference time for your model you may avoid saving these.

---

The sizes when saving:

```
torch.save(model,'model.pth')
torch.save(model.state_dict(),'state_dict.pth')
```

should be: `model.pth > state_dict.pth` because state dict is included into the model.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I deleted my last answer since I was wrong, as of pytorch version `1.1.0a0+863818e`, using:

```
torch.save(model,'model.pth')
```

And using:

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(),'state_dict.pth')
```

Gave the same results on size for both, are you using you are loading the nets correctly? Proof:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bpinaya bpinaya  14M Aug  8 10:26 model.pth
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bpinaya bpinaya  14M Aug  8 10:27 state_dict.pth
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bpinaya bpinaya 528M Aug  8 10:29 vgg.pth
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bpinaya bpinaya 528M Aug  8 10:29 vggstate_dict.pth
```

Comment: I have been doing some `forward`s before saving the model, probably the buffers are still there but i really can't see them in the dictionary

Comment: Your original answer was not wrong. Actually saving model and model.state_dict() will have different sizes, slightly different when models are big. ;)